# Set margins/constraints for UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

Is there any way to set margins or constraints for UIViewControllers?

I have this structure

```
UIWindow
 - UINavigationController
  - UICollectionView
```

I would like to layout so that the UINavigationController does not use the space under the status bar, and the UICollectionView to not use the space under my custom toolbar in the UINavigationController.

Is there any way to set constraints (programmatically) for view controllers similar to how you can set it to views? Or any other way to achieve this behaviour?

My UICollectionView has a different background color and currently that gets set under the status bar as well.

Comment: You can't set constraints on controllers, only on views, so the solution to your problem is somewhere in setting proper constraints on views to achieve the hierarchy you need.

Comment: How would I go about setting a constraint on the views such that the Collection View, and preferably also the navigation controller does not get placed under the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

With collection views (and table views and other `UIScrollView` subclasses) you do want them to display under your navigation bar and status bar so (if the bar is translucent) the content will be seen through it as you scroll.

What you don't want is the content to get stuck under these bars so it can't be seen. You do this by setting the scroll view's `contentInset` property so the content doesn't require the top part of the scroll view to be visible.

Here's how you might set the `contentInset` property so the content doesn't interfere with the status bar and navigation bar on top and a tab bar at the bottom:

```
 self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0f, 0.0f, 49.0f, 0.0f);
```